# How to super() call with complex arguments in Dart?

Tags: dart

Up to what I researched, in Dart you gotta call super outside the function body of the constructor.

Suppose this situation:

```
/// Unmodifiable given class
class Figure{
  final int sides;
  const Figure(this.sides);
}

/// Own class
class Shape extends Figure{
  Shape(Form form){
    if(form is Square) super(4);
    else if(form is Triangle) super(3);
  }
}
```

That throws analysis errors (the superclass doesn't have 0 parameters constructor & the expression super(3) doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked). How could I achieve the desidered functionality of the example?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Dart for calling the super constructor the *initializer list* is used.

```
class Shape extends Figure{
  Shape(Form form) : super(form is Square ? 4 : form is Triangle ? 3 : null);
}
```

if you need to execute statements you can add a factory constructor that forwards to a (private) regular constructor like

```
class Shape extends Figure{

  factory Shape(Form form) {
    if (form is Square) return new Shape._(4);
    else if(form is Triangle) return new Shape._(3);
  }
  Shape._(int sides) : super(sides)
}
```

Comment: For more explanation on Factory Constructor, one can check this blog: https://medium.com/run-dart/dart-dartlang-introduction-advanced-dart-features-524de79456b9#:~:text=Factory%20Constructors,to%20control%20the%20instance%20creation.